# Probabilities of eigenfunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, probability, born-rule

I am struggling to understand how to get the probabilities of each eigenstate occurring from a wavefunction that is a linear combination of eigenfunctions. If we have a wavefunction

$$\Psi = A ( e^{ikx}+\frac{1}{\sqrt3}e^{2ikx}+\frac{1}{\sqrt5}e^{3ikx}), $$

from my understanding, the momentum eigenstates will be $\hbar k$, $2\hbar k$ or $3 \hbar k$. However how do you get the probabilities of each of these occuring?

Apparently the answer is 15/23, 5/23 or 3/23? I am struggling to find where this 23 come from. Many thanks!

Comment: Hint: you need to determine $A$ by imposing that the state is properly normalized ...

Comment: I may be doing to wrong however this wavefunction seems impossible to normalise. I put the integral $ A^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Psi \Psi^{*} dx $ into an online calculator and it could not give me a result. Is there any other way?

Comment: @SuchAgoodDoge yes the example is not so good academically because plane waves cannot be normalized in the standard way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ended up understanding this best is as follows:

1. Get the momentum Eigenvalues straight from the exponents of the momentum Eigenvectors in the wavefunction. Since
   $$ \Psi = A ( e^{ikx}+\frac{1}{\sqrt3}e^{2ikx}+\frac{1}{\sqrt5}e^{3ikx}), $$
   we get $p=\hbar k, 2\hbar k, 3\hbar k$
2. Get the uncertainties by squaring the values before each eigenvector then dividing by the total square as shown in the table bellow.
   \begin{array} {|r|r|r|}
   \hline
   P &N &|N|^2 & \frac{|N|^2}{\sum{N^2}}\\
   \hline
   \hbar k & 1 & 1 & \frac{15}{23}\\
   \hline
   2 \hbar k & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{5}{23}\\
   \hline
   3 \hbar k & \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{3}{23} \\
   \hline
   \end{array}
   We therefore see that the probability of each eigenstate occuring is $\frac{|N|^2}{\sum{N^2}}$

3. The expectation value on the momentum <$p$> is equal to
   $$ \sum_i{p_i \frac{|N_i|^2}{\sum_k{N_k^2}}} $$
   In this case;
   $$ <p> = \hbar k \frac{15}{23} + 2\hbar k \frac{5}{23} + 3\hbar k \frac{3}{23} = \frac{31}{23} \hbar k$$

Answer (score 2):

15+5+3=23. Probability must add to one.

Note added: The ratios are

$$
1+ \frac 13 +  \frac 1 5 = \frac{15+ 5+ 3}{15}= \frac {23}{15}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand this however where does the 15 come from? Many thanks

Comment: Added note on adding fractions.